# Edittext perdendo foco no cabeçalho da ListView

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

Coloquei um `header` na minha `ListView` pois queria que ele rolasse junto com ela. Nesse cabeçalho há dois `EditText`, quando clico no segundo, o foco volta pro primeiro em menos de um segundo. Não dá sequer tempo de escrever nada no segundo campo, e sempre que clico acontece isso, alguém tem alguma ideia do que é? (Tirei o código geral da activity pra ficar menor)

```
class ConfigActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.config)

        var header = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.config_header, null)
        lvOptions.addHeaderView(header)

        var adapter = OptionsAdapter(this, ArrayList<Option>()) //só pra criar o adapter da listview, vazia mesmo, só com o header
        lvOptions.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

aqui o config_header.xml (No config.xml tem só o ListView e no Adapter não tem nada referente ao Header)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nome"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTRendaM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Renda mensal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que provavelmente está acontecendo é que quando vc clica no ListView(seja o click para scrollar ou o click de fato), o observable dele, que está por debaixo dos panos, vai fazer aquele processo todo pra avisar a todos os items que estão sob o controle dele que "algo aconteceu". Esse "avisar que algo aconteceu" faz com que tudo seja recarregado. E ai está o problema. Tudo vai voltar pro default, que no seu caso é o primeiro EditText com foco.

O que eu faria seria tirar esses editText ai de dentro. Tem uma forma de fazer isso que vc quer com o AppBarLayout e CoordinatorLayout, usando o atributo `layout_scrollFlags`.

Um exemplo de activitiy seria:
Onde, `container` seria commitado um fragment que tem seu ListView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="algumaFlagAqui">

            <!-- Seus dois editText vão aqui dentro desse layout -->

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Esses links podem te ajudar a enxergar a solução:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328695/what-is-the-difference-between-appbarlayout-vs-toolbar

http://karthikraj.net/2016/12/24/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android/

Boa Sorte!

Comment: No caso eu colocaria meus Edittext como um "toolbar" que se "esconderia" quando a listview der scroll pra baixo e aparecer novamente quando der scroll pra cima?

Comment: Exatamente isso. Provavelmente a flag que vc vai usar vai ser a `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`. Porém tem algumas outras que podem servir pro seu caso.

Comment: tem certeza se o ListView funciona com o AppBarLayout? tentei aqui e não deu certo, também tentei com ScrollView e não deu, já com o NestedScrollView funcionou, acho eu que só deve funcionar com RecyclerView no lugar do ListView, vou tentar implementar ele

Comment: Funciona sim. Mas já que vc ta usando o RecyclerView, esse exemplo aqui é bom: https://mobikul.com/hideshow-toolbar-scrolling/